# Java7 creating converter,Interface or static methods?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, converters, static-methods

In a project,I have classes A,B.I have to convert A to B and also B to A.There is two approaches to convert them:

1- Creating an utility class with static methods like this:

```
public class converter{
    public static A convertBToA() {
        ...
    }

    public static B convertAToB() {
        ...
    }
}
```

2- Creating an interface like this:

```
public interface Converter {
    public <T> T convert(Class<T> type, Object value);
}
```

Then implement it by a class and override converter method to convert A to B and vise versa.I know both of above ways are possible,but I like to have a **good design**.So, which way is better?

**Notes**:

**1-** I use java 7,so Interface bodies can not contain static methods.
**2-** As [immibis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106104/immibis) commented here,Answer depends on situations.But I looks for ways that match Design Principles.Specially minimum time for maintenance and developing.

Comment: I would choose the second option, so you respect the open-closed principle...

Comment: It depends on what A and B are. You want to make it easy to change things later, but you also don't want to overcomplicate things (which the second option might well do).

Comment: Option 3: Use a mapping framework like [Dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer) or [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/).

Comment: This might belong on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @BudaGavril Please add your comment as answer.It points to a Design Pattern Principle.

Comment: Thank you for your attentions and times.I looks for  ways that match Design Principles.Specially minimum time for maintenance and developing  .

Answer (score 3):

I think your second approach is a little too generic.
I'd use something like

```
public interface Converter<Src,Dst> {
    public Dst convert(Src value);
}
```

and then make specific classes for each combination of types required, like

```
public class ABConverter implements Converter<A,B> {
    @Override
    public B convert(A value) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Spring support this idea, for more info take a look at this interface **org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter**

Answer (score 3):

You should try out [Orika](http://code.google.com/p/orika/) or [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). These Frameworks do these kind of stuff well. If it is just some classes you need to convert then a interface would be fine in my opinion. Another solution could be providing a constructor (or static factory method) in A which takes a B and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to design without class convert?
Suppose, you convert A to B in order to use some function in B, eg. `b.sleep()`. I prefer implement Interface.

```
interface Runable{
    void run();
}

interface Sleepable{
    void sleep();
}


class A implements  Runable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //run
    }
}

class B implements  Sleepable, Runable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //run
    }


    @Override
    public void sleep() {
        //sleep
    }
}
```

Maybe help you

PS: If I want to convert A to B, I will do it in B's constructor, or B's instance function(prefered , because function has name)

```
public class B {
    public static B instanceWithA(A a){
    //A->B
    }
}
```

vice versa

Comment: Thank you! But that is not my purpose.I want to convert them.

Comment: I add a supply, maybe help you.